# how to transform this list contain multiple dictionaries and i want flatten list inside a list ? it is possible to do ? i want response shown below

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

Suppose you have a List like:

```
     [{'name': 'Jon', 'values': [{'value': 'Decent'}, {'value': 'Average'}]},
     {'name': 'grunion', 'values': [{'value': 'Junk'}, {'value': 'Bad'}]},
     {'name': 'Mark', 'values': [{'value': 'Excellent'}, {'value': 'Very good'}]}]
```

it is possible to get convert into this kind of list :

```
         [{'name': 'Jon', 'values': ['Decent' ,'Average']},
         {'name': 'grunion', 'values': ['Junk', 'Bad']},
         {'name': 'Mark', 'values': ['Excellent', 'Very good']}]
```

thank you in advance! I am new to python so please try to help I know it easy problem but I am not getting it how to make it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the nested dictionaries and update the values for `'values'`:

```py
dictionary =[{'name': 'Jon', 'values': [{'value': 'Decent'}, {'value': 'Average'}]},
     {'name': 'grunion', 'values': [{'value': 'Junk'}, {'value': 'Bad'}]},
     {'name': 'Mark', 'values': [{'value': 'Excellent'}, {'value': 'Very good'}]}]

for d in dictionary:
    d.update({'values': [nest_d['value'] for nest_d in d['values']]})

print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```py
[{'name': 'Jon', 'values': ['Decent', 'Average']}, {'name': 'grunion', 'values': ['Junk', 'Bad']}, {'name': 'Mark', 'values': ['Excellent', 'Very good']}]
```

In this loop, we first iterare over all the dictionaries in the list using `d`. For all those dictionaries, we have to update the `values` key by creating a list using list comprehension that loops over the nested dictionaries `nest_d` and gets the `value` values. The structuring of the dictionary makes the code a bit hard to understand at first glance but I hope you see what it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can you dict comprehenstion and define a processing function:

```
lst = [
    {'name': 'Jon', 'values': [{'value': 'Decent'}, {'value': 'Average'}]},
    {'name': 'grunion', 'values': [{'value': 'Junk'}, {'value': 'Bad'}]},
    {'name': 'Mark', 'values': [{'value': 'Excellent'}, {'value': 'Very good'}]},
]


def transform(obj: dict):
    return {"name": obj['name'], "values": [val['value'] for val in obj['values']]}


res = [transform(obj) for obj in lst]

print(res)

# [{'name': 'Jon', 'values': ['Decent', 'Average']}, {'name': 'grunion', 'values': ['Junk', 'Bad']}, {'name': 'Mark', 'values': ['Excellent', 'Very good']}]
```